# Ember Div as bound view

Tags: html, ember.js, ember-data

I have a simple little ember app, except for one complication.  One of the fields in my view is an HTML form designer.  What I'd like to do is have an ember view where I can bind a property in my MODEL to the HTML of a div.  Is it possible in Ember to have an input field be a div?

Comment: why do you want it to be a div?

Comment: the content of the property is an html string.  it has to be a div so that the user can see the content rendered, rather than raw html source code as in a text area.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using an `{{{ }}}` to output a html safe string.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <p>Source (HTML)</p>
  {{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding=source}}
  <hr/> 
  <p>Preview:</p>
  <div>{{{source}}}</div>
</script>
```

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/mgrassotti/DyUDT/1/